Error: Bad state: The FormData has already been finalized for Dio Interceptor
I am using Dio Interceptor for RefreshToken. However, whenever I make a request to the backend and the token has already expired while I'm using FormData in my request, it returns an error: "Error: Bad state: The FormData has already been finalized due to the retry mechanism Dio is using after regenerating a valid token."
H
   MyApiProvider() {
    _dio.interceptors.add(InterceptorsWrapper(
      onRequest: (options, handler) async {
        options.headers["Accept"] = "application";
        String? token = _getStorage.read("accessToken");
        options.headers["Authorization"] = 'Bearer $token';
        return handler.next(options);
      },
      onError: (error, handler) async {
        if (error.response?.statusCode == 401) {
          final newAccessToken = await refreshToken();
          if (newAccessToken != null) {
            _dio.options.headers["Authorization"] = 'Bearer $newAccessToken';
            return handler.resolve(await _dio.fetch(error.requestOptions));
          }
        }
        return handler.next(error);
      },
    ));
  }

And also here is the request Function code.
  Future<void> uploadMultipleImages({
    required dio.FormData formData,
    required List<String> imagePaths,
    required Map<String, dynamic> bodyData,
    required Function(List<String>) onUploadComplete,
    required String endpoint,
  }) async {
    if (imagePaths.isEmpty) {
      return;
    }

    try {
      for (int i = 0; i < imagePaths.length; i++) {
        File file = File(imagePaths[i]);
        String fileName = file.path.split('/').last;

        // Add file to FormData
        formData.files.add(MapEntry(
          'multiple_images',
          await dio.MultipartFile.fromFile(
            file.path,
            filename: fileName,
          ),
        ));

        // Add additional data to FormData
        bodyData.forEach((key, value) {
          formData.fields.add(MapEntry(key, value.toString()));
        });

        final response = await _dio.post(
          endpoint,
          data: formData,
          options: dio.Options(
            contentType: dio.Headers.formUrlEncodedContentType,
          ),
        );

        final message = response.data["message"].toString();
        _getStorage.writeIfNull('vIsApproved', false);
        SnackBarUtils.showSnackBar("Success", message);
      }
    } on DioException catch (error) {
      throw DioErrors.mapDioExceptionToHttpError(error);
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
      rethrow;
    }
  }

I have made some research as well and I got to know that it need to new instance of formData but i have tried all i could but no result, and I have also tried to check for token expiring before making the request still doesn't give me a better result.
What can i do?

I have use method .clone thats solved my same problem, but clone will deprecate soon.. can you share your ans?

I couldn’t get a proper solution to it but what I did was to make a refresh token request before the upload function request occur.

use formData.clone this will solve problem. there misunderstanding that i thought it will be deprecated. it developer confirm that it won't.  So feel free to use formData.clone

Alright thank you. Can you paste that section of the code ? I will really appreciate that.

you need to create a new instance of "formdata" for each request..
    Future<void> uploadMultipleImages({
  required List<String> imagePaths,
  required Map<String, dynamic> bodyData,
  required Function(List<String>) onUploadComplete,
  required String endpoint,
}) async {
  if (imagePaths.isEmpty) {
    return;
  }

  try {
    for (int i = 0; i < imagePaths.length; i++) {
      File file = File(imagePaths[i]);
      String fileName = file.path.split('/').last;

      FormData formData = FormData();

      formData.files.add(MapEntry(
        'multiple_images',
        await MultipartFile.fromFile(
          file.path,
          filename: fileName,
        ),
      ));

      bodyData.forEach((key, value) {
        formData.fields.add(MapEntry(key, value.toString()));
      });

      final response = await _dio.post(
        endpoint,
        data: formData,
        options: Options(
          contentType: Headers.formUrlEncodedContentType,
        ),
      );

      final message = response.data["message"].toString();
      _getStorage.writeIfNull('vIsApproved', false);
      SnackBarUtils.showSnackBar("Success", message);
    }
  } on DioError catch (error) {
    if (error.response?.statusCode == 401) {
      // Handle token expiration
      final newAccessToken = await refreshToken();
      if (newAccessToken != null) {
        
        _dio.options.headers["Authorization"] = 'Bearer $newAccessToken';
        await uploadMultipleImages(
          imagePaths: imagePaths,
          bodyData: bodyData,
          onUploadComplete: onUploadComplete,
          endpoint: endpoint,
        );
        return;
      }
    }
    throw DioErrors.mapDioExceptionToHttpError(error);
  } catch (e) {
    print(e);
    rethrow;
  }
}


I have tried, that before still not working, that's why I pass the formData to the function parameter, to make sure it get new instance of formData
